# Using Prism IEventAggregator cross platform

Tags: prism

We have some library project C# code that needs to signal events to the main WPF application. We would like to reuse the library code (.NET core 3.1 based) on Mac and Linux. If we use IEventAggregator in the library code, could this be reused in a net core linux or mac app?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [EventAggregator](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Source/Prism/Events/EventAggregator.cs) is in the platfrom-independent part of prism, and you can use it from the net framework, net core, xamarin android or ios, whatever you like. For example, publish an event in the library and subscribe to it in the mac app or publish an event in the linux app and subscribe to it in the library...

Make sure, though, that your events are platform-independent, too, because you have to reference them to publish or subscribe.